# Print/find element from nested array

Tags: java, rest-assured

Could please, someone assist in asserting at least one element from nested array with REST Assured?
Below is part of array which element I want to extract (i.e 5,41, or 2,78):

```
"visible": {
        "zone": [
            [
                [
                    5.41,
                    3.58
                ],
                [
                    6.23,
                    2.78
                ],
        ],
        "type": "array"
    },
```

Only which succeeded is to confirm is 'not Null':

```
Response response = given().param(parameterOne).param(parameterTwo).
            get("http://URI/api/zone");

    response.jsonPath().prettyPrint();

        response
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .body("$.size()", greaterThan(0))
                .body("[0].visible.zone", notNullValue());
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want *every* nested array to contain at least one value from a specified list (for example: `[5.41, 2.78]`)?

Comment: @JanezKuhar No, just to assert with few numbers (i.e 5,41 & 2,78) that response has correct values
Array is much much bigger with 50 nested arrays in it, with different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with following line:

```
.body("[0].visible.zone[0][0][0]", is(5.41));
```